# Автоматический запуск bat-скрипта под администратором

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Сделал скрипт, который должен создавать хардлинки в текущую папку для объектов, переданных в параметрах. Единственный нюанс: **mklink** требует прав администратора, поэтому скрипт отлично работает из командной строки запущенной под админом, но не работает при запуске напрямую. Проблема в том, что он как раз писался для того, чтобы запускаться напрямую: дропаешь на него файлы и он автоматически создает хардлинки на них там, где надо. Сейчас к сожалению это не работает, поскольку из эксплорера он запускается без нужных прав.

Отсюда вопрос: можно ли настроить автоматический запуск скрипта под админом (настроек совместимости с галочкой run as administrator у батников нет, увы), либо, может, есть способ получить нужные права внутри скрипта во время выполнения?

Comment: Есть способы повысить привилегии у батника. Но если они пониженные (обычный пользователь), то все равно появится окно UAC, в котором пользователь должен нажать подтверждение. Вам такой вариант нужен?

Comment: Да, подойдет. Всяко лучше, чем прописывать файлы руками.

Comment: Тогда возьмите любой вариант на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985) и добавьте к нему свой код. Есть и другие варианты: создать триггер, который будет запускать Ваш батник, или использовать ПО на подобие win-sudo.       P.S. лично мне нравится **elevate.cmd**